# Can't get data from database and render into table in UI

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection

I connected to the database in server.js file and fetch data in DataSensor.jsx by calling API '/api/getAll'. But my UI didn't render anything, and I open console log, it showed me "Error fetching sensor data: AxiosError". Please help me, I'm newbie.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/datasensors.css'
const DataSensors = () => {

    const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/getAll');
                console.log('Data received:', response.data);
                setSensorData(response.data);

    return (
        <div className='container__data'>
            <table className='data-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Temperature</th>
                        <th>Humidity</th>
                        <th>Brightness</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {sensorData.map((data) => (
                        <tr key={data.id}>
                            <td>{data.id}</td>
                            <td>{data.temperature}</td>
                            <td>{data.humidity}</td>
                            <td>{data.brightness}</td>
                            <td>{data.createdAt}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataSensors;
```

And here's my server.js to connect to mysql database

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3002;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'iot'
});

app.get('/api/getAll', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM datasensors';

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if( err ) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', err);
            res.status(500).json({err: 'Internal Server Error'});
        } else {
            console.log('Data from database:', result);
            res.status(200).json(result); 
        }
    });
});

db.connect(err => {
    if( err ) {
        console.error("Lỗi kết nối tới cơ sở dữ liệu MySQL: " + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Kết nối thành công đến cơ sở dữ liệu MySQL");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server đang lắng nghe tại http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is little bit buggy
you were not calling the function and issue was in useEffect here is updated code hope it will help you

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
const DataSensors = () => {

const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('/api/getAll');
            console.log('Data received:', response.data);
            setSensorData(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error', error)
        }
    }
    fetchData();
}
    , []);  // Empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like component


return (
    <div className='container__data'>
        <table className='data-table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Temperature</th>
                    <th>Humidity</th>
                    <th>Brightness</th>
                    <th>Created At</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {sensorData.map((data) => (
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                        <td>{data.id}</td>
                        <td>{data.temperature}</td>
                        <td>{data.humidity}</td>
                        <td>{data.brightness}</td>
                        <td>{data.createdAt}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataSensors;
```

Comment: Actually I had added it to my code but I deleted when i posted this question =(((. I have edited this question to avoid misunderstanding. Thanks for your comment